# SQL IN Operator and associating values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a method using the IN operator to associate values to each value inside the IN statement?

For example:

```
 SELECT Foo FROM MyTable WHERE Item IN('XYZ' AS 'BOB', 'QRM' AS 'DAVID')
```

I want to basically associate an alias to the returned response.

Example response:

```
BOB   | 23
DAVID | 3
```

Comment: Please tag the db and also give a sample of how your input and output looks

Comment: You can create a temp table with item & alias values, and then join that in your SELECT query or you can use CASE statement for Item column in your SELECT query, but nothing like alias inside IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't do this with `IN`.  You do this with `VALUES()` and `JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.othername, . . .
FROM MyTable t JOIN
     (VALUES ('XYZ', 'BOB'),
             ('QRM', 'DAVID')
     ) v(item, othername)
     ON t.item = v.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `IN` absolutely won't get you there. Maybe you're searching for a `CASE ... END`? With it you could "translate" the strings like this:

```
SELECT CASE item
         WHEN 'XYZ'
           THEN 'BOB'
         WHEN 'QRM'
           THEN 'DAVID'
         ELSE
           item
       END item,
       value
       FROM foo;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f8db942986cbf1158caed6ef230eb0a)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add aliases in the `IN` clause... but I'm also not sure why you would want to?
You can add 'aliases' in the SELECT clause though.

I'm assuming that your data structure looks like:

```
Item     |  Value
------------------
XYZ      |     23
QRM      |      3
```

So you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE Item
        WHEN 'XYZ' THEN 'BOB'
        WHEN 'QRM' THEN 'DAVID'
        ELSE 'SOMEONE ELSE'
    END AS Name,
    Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE Item IN ('XYZ', 'QRM')
```